# System.Drawing.Imaging BitmapData color components order

Tags: c#, bitmap, system.drawing.imaging

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#remarks):

> ...The format also defines the order of the color components within a single pixel of data.

Where is the order documented? I know that, for example,locking the bitmap with format `24bppRgb` gives me a region in memory filled with pixel data in the form:

1. **B**(first byte)- **G**(second) - **R**(third)
2. Each row has an alignment of 4 byte

I found "2" in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.stride?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#remarks), however I didn't manage to find anything about "1" (color component order). Could you help me find that info somewhere in the documentation?

Comment: It depends on the pixel format. And though `PixelFormat`'s documentation is not detailed very well either, [here](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/T_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_KnownPixelFormat.htm) you can find a more detailed description from a fairly compatible library. Btw. the library [allows](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing#fast-bitmap-manipulation) you to access the bitmap data of any pixel format in the same way, which doesn't require to bother with the actual color layout and is also very performant (disclaimer: written by me).

Comment: Thanks @GyörgyKőszeg. I'll take a look at that library. However, where can I find something equivalent to `KnownPixelFormat` documentation, where the color component order is well defined for a format, for `System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat`?

Comment: Unfortunately `PixelFormat`'s documentation doesn't go into the details very much. But exception with the 48/64 bpp formats my `KnownPixelFormat` is completely compatible with `PixelFormat`. You can fond more `System.Drawing`-specific pixel format related information [here](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_ImageExtensions_ConvertPixelFormat_1.htm) (see the table and also the notes below it). Please note that the actual behavior is platform dependent (Windows vs. Linux[/Mono] vs. ReactOS)